# Unity3D C# выпадающий список в скрипте через enum

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужен выпадающий список у скрипта в инспекторе. 
На данный момент в скрипте есть

```
public enum OPTIONS
{
    CUBE = 0,
    SPHERE = 1,
    PLANE = 2
}
```

Но в инспекторе это никак не отображается, выбрать пункт нельзя.

Далее должно быть что то вроде

```
if(OPTIONS == OPTIONS.CUBE)
{ 
  //некий код
}
```

Но подчеркивает слово OPTIONS в

```
  if(OPTIONS == OPTIONS.CUBE)
```

И пишет что
"test.OPTIONS' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Соответственно, ничего не работает, и вопрос в следующем.

Как получить через enum выпадающий список в инспекторе, и потом его использовать в скрипте далее?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение нашлось в стандартных ассетах юнити - там немало скриптов с выпадающим списком в инспекторе. По аналогии делаем и мы.

Делается он в два этапа:
Сначала создаем сам список

```
public enum OPTIONS
{
CUBE = 0,
SPHERE = 1,
PLANE = 2
}
```

Потом создаем экземпляр этого списка

```
public OPTIONS opt;
```

И оно уже появляется в инспекторе.

Теперь дело за малым - применить его. Делается это так

```
 if (opt == OPTIONS.CUBE)
{
//Делаем что надо
}
```

Comment: ответ абсолютно правильный. Почему он все еще не отмечен как коректный ответ?